# Android - ListView items maintaining style when scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-listview

I know that similar questions have already been asked but I do not understand what would be the correct approach of solving the issue, yet.

I would like to change the background color of a ListView row when the user clicks it. However due to Android reusing the row layouts when scrolling, the background color gets repeated for other rows. I am wondering what would be the correct approach of maintaining the original layout for all rows except the one changed programmaticaly and also maintain the changed layout information for that row for scrolling back. I am using a SimpleAdapter which is passed the rows layout's XML.

Regards

Comment: When you select an item from your listview it doesnt automatically uses the default color(usually blue) for that selected item background?

Comment: Well, changing the background is just an example that demonstrates the issue I am facing. My rows layout actually contains multiple views which I would like to manipulate upon selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rows' capabilities within your ListView largely depend on the kind of Adapter you are using. In any Adapter where you manually construct or inflate the View per item, you can change the layout properties per item, as long as you do so *within* the Adapter. Simply add your background color code to when the item's View is built, and it will work like a charm. If you are not able to do so with the current Adapter, consider extending the current one or using a different adapter.

**Note:** I haven't placed code directly within this answer because where you add it depends upon your own implementation. For instance, I would add `.setBackgroundDrawable()` to `bindView()` in an extended `CursorAdapter`.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks FuzzicalLogic! Your answer gave me the necessary certainty to look into manually inflating the views. So I am now overriding the SimpleAdapter's getView method inflating each row's view based on the corresponding data element. When a ListView item is clicked I update this information so the view is created reflecting this change when getView is called again for the same item (when becoming visible again).

Comment: Certainly, be mindful. Creating custom adapters is not complicated, but you will run into issues the first few times. I have a ListView that has 19 individual views. It was my first custom adapter within Android and it screwed with me for about 4 days. :)